# How to handle the states of entities using DbEntityEntry?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am watching CodeCamper tutorial by John Papa, and I come across a code in the EFRepository class. and its hard to find me why he uses DbEntityEntry and also when I am looking for the details of DbEntityEntry.State property, I see that they have been talking about some Graph like:

EF will automatically attach detached objects in the graph when setting the state of an entity or when SaveChanges() is called.

please tell me what does these means.

Here is the class looks like:

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        }
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

   public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Added)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WPF application your entities stay in memory all the time so you can do this:

```
var cakeProduct = new Product{ProductName = "Cake"};
MyContext.ProductsDbSet.Add();
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

and (some time later)

```
cakeProduct.ProductName = "Chocolate Cake";
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

and

```
MyContext.ProductsDbSet.Remove(cakeProduct);
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

But if you have a ASP .Net MVC app you have to respond to a call

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product someProduct){
   //someProduct has only just been created in memory
   var context = new MyContext(); //the Context does not exist yet
   context.ProductsRepository.Update(someProduct);
}
```